# Java - Create a list of an array of fixed 40 elements

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

Sorry if there is a similar question in here, but I have a bit of trouble creating a list (unfixed dimension) of another list or array of fixed dimension (40 elements in this case).

So far I have created a class with a method to add values(string) at a specific position.

```
public class t_Info_Loan_Class  {
   private String[] t_Info_Loan;

   t_Info_Loan_Class() {
       t_Info_Loan = new String[40];
   }

    private void add(String s, int j) {
        t_Info_Loan[j] = s;
    }
};
```

Then I tried a simple addition:

```
t_Info_Loan_Class[] t_Info_Loan_Tab = new t_Info_Loan_Class[40];

   for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
      t_Info_Loan_Tab[i] = new t_Info_Loan_Class();

   for(int j = 0; j < 40; j++)
       t_Info_Loan_Tab[0].add("S", j);
   for(int j = 0; j < 40; j++)
       t_Info_Loan_Tab[1].add("D", j);

   for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      for(int j = 0; j < 40; j++)
         System.out.print(t_Info_Loan_Tab[i].t_Info_Loan[j] + " ");
      System.out.println();
   }
```

From this, I get a `NullPointerException`.
My intention is to generate:

```
S S S ... S  (40 times)
D D D ... D  (40 times)
```

Thanks!

Comment: you are trying to call .add() method on t_Info_Loan_Tab[0] , which doesn't refer to any object.

Comment: A new array of `t_Info_Loan_Class[40]` has spaces for 40 `t_Info_Loan_Class`, but you need to put instances into those spaces.

Comment: btw I guess you are trying to call private method also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are initializing the `array` of `t_Info_Loan_Class`, but you are not initializing the objects themselves.

Before calling any member method, you should create your instances

```
for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
    t_Info_Loan_Tab[i] = new t_Info_Loan_Tab("string");
```

Comment: Actually, none of the holder objects are initialized, only the array that holds them. The desired output is only to print 2 lists of 40 strings.

Comment: @urgentx that's what my answer is about

Comment: Understood, I was just addressing your confusion about initializing only the first two objects.

Comment: Tried adding the instances (for i < 2, I want only 2 objects just for tests), and I get "Cannot find symbol"

Comment: @payloc Updated

Comment: yes `t_Info_Loan_Class[] t_Info_Loan_Tab = new t_Info_Loan_Class[40]` that is not correct, because in this case every item in the array will be null

Comment: Made it work now, forgot to put `static` to the class